# How to link a C++ library in a C project

Tags: c++, c

The c project is composed by a lot of classes and files. The C++ library is compiled into a ".a" file. When I add the .a file as library to the MakeFile of the C project, it shows a lot of errors like `undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'` that may related to the difference between C and C++.

I'm using gcc to compile the C project. But whatever functions I'm calling in the C project are declared as `extern C` in the header file of the C++ library.

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a C++ linker, or use `g++` as the link driver instead of `gcc`.

The issue is that the basic linker will not link against C++ runtime libraries (the same would be true for a Fortran static library). The C++ driver for your compiler will add these flags for you.

Comment: Does `main` have to be C++ for that, or does it also work if `main` is C?

Comment: No, you can have any type of `main`. It's just the runtime libraries, what C++ needs to run, that you have to integrated s they are not in the static library.

Comment: Thanks! Compile with gcc and then link with g++ solved the problem!